# Increasing memory by downgrading from SSD to HDD in laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, memory, ssd, zenbook

I have an ASUS Zenbook that came factory installed with a 120gb SSD. I want to increase my memory and was looking at a 2TB HDD of the same physical dimensions (HDD is 3mm thicker).

Q: So my first question is if this is feasible to begin with: **Can I replace my SSD with an HDD without causing any system problems or functionality differences?** I realize the machine wouldn't boot as fast or perform memory retrieval tasks as the SSD would allow.

Q: Would a HDD cause significant heating problems as the machine was built/designed for a solid state drive? Currently, the machine never gets hot on the bottom unless I'm playing a game or watching a movie. I've opened it once in the 10 months I've had it and cleaned out some dust, but not a lot. Everything runs smoothly, no problems yet (knock on wood).

For what it's worth, I also have a 1TB external hard drive so would leaving that connected for extended periods of time be a possible solution?

Comment: *"I want to increase my memory"* -- Seems like you really mean "increase the *storage capacity*  of a laptop computer?  "Memory" typically refers to RAM (or a brain function), not mass storage.  BTW something that's *"3mm thicker"*  is not *"of the same physical dimensions"*.  IOW it won't fit.

Comment: @sawdust you're right (told you I'm not a hardware guy). My current SSD is 7mm and I found a WD Blue 1TB that is 7mm and from the reviews, it looks like this one is perfect. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you replace a sdd with a hdd.  YES  Will it fit? Maybe, some ultra thin device and not thick enough, and some are.  You need to measure with a ruler.

Most hard drives don't produce a significant amount of heat, and overheating isn't an issue.

You can leave you external hard drive plugged in as much as you want.